# How make a list in the Info Window of a Fusion Map from a comma separated list?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Can a cell with comma separated information be turned into a list? I've got uneven amounts of data (companies) and would like to just have it display as a basic List when the flag is clicked on in the Fusion Map.

Say I have:

```
Location: Seminole County, FL

Companies: Acme Co, Box Inc, Cogs LLC

------

Location: Orange County, FL

Companies: Acme Co, Dirt Inc, Shell Co
```

On Map it should be two flags, which it is. But how can I then have the companies displayed as a basic list?

I can go into the record and change it to contain the HTML:

```
Companies:<ul><li>Acme Co</li><li>Box Inc</li><li>Shell Co</li></ul
```

but that's pretty clunky. Is there a way to template it into the Custom Info Window to automate this:

[image: Custom Info Window Layout - Google Fusion]

I looked online but couldn't find anything and the [Fusion User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fusion-tables-users-group/_v_NhtWZdG0) says to ask here.

**Edit:**

Based on first answer, my rows:

[image: Fusion Rows]

Resulting problem:

[image: Fusion Map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you format the Companies values as JSON lists, you can loop over them with Closure templates. The latter are described in this [help page](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/3081246?hl=en), though the looping constructs are not currently documented.

First, go to Edit > Change columns and set the format of the Companies to JSON text. Then format your values as, say, ["Acme Co", "Dirt Inc", "Shell Co"]. Then in the Closure template you can loop over it it with

```
{template .contents}
...wrapper div and other columns if desired...
Companies:
<ul>
{foreach $company in $data.value.Companies}
<li>{$company}
{/foreach}
</ul>
...other stuff...
{/template}
```

Comment: Returns error: "In 'foreach' command {foreach $company in $data.value.Companies}
$company{/foreach}, the data reference does not resolve to a SoyList (encountered type com.google.template.soy.data.restricted.StringData$ConstantString)."

Comment: What was the format of the string it was looking at? Try removing the foreach and just printing the column value to ensure they are all JSON lists. You can also test if a value is a list with {if isList($data.value.Companies)}.

Comment: Updated the question with screenshots, think I followed your answer exactly

Comment: Ah, you'll also need to change the Companies column format to JSON text; I'd forgotten about that. Another problem is that it should be {$company}, not just$company.